# ip6tables block thunderbird email

Tags: ipv6, ip6tables

The following ip6tables block thunderbird from retrieving email from my gmail account:

```
sudo ip6tables -P FORWARD DROP
sudo ip6tables -P INPUT DROP
sudo ip6tables -P OUTPUT DROP

sudo ip6tables -A INPUT  -j ACCEPT -i lo 
sudo ip6tables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -o lo 

sudo ip6tables -A INPUT  -j ACCEPT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED
sudo ip6tables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED

sudo ip6tables -A INPUT -p icmpv6 -j ACCEPT 
sudo ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p icmpv6 -j ACCEPT

sudo ip6tables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -p tcp --dport 53  -m comment --comment "DNS/TCP"
sudo ip6tables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -p udp --dport 53  -m comment --comment "DNS/UDP"
sudo ip6tables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -p tcp --dport 22  -m comment --comment "SSH secure shell"
sudo ip6tables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -p tcp --dport 80  -m comment --comment "HTTP"
sudo ip6tables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -p tcp --dport 443 -m comment --comment "HTTPS"
sudo ip6tables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -p tcp --dport 110 -m comment --comment "POP3"
sudo ip6tables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -p tcp --dport 143 -m comment --comment "IMAP"
sudo ip6tables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -p tcp --dport 993 -m comment --comment "IMAP/SSL"
sudo ip6tables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -p tcp --dport 25  -m comment --comment "SMTP"
sudo ip6tables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -p tcp --dport 26  -m comment --comment "SMTP 2nd"
sudo ip6tables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -p tcp --dport 465 -m comment --comment "SMTP/SSL"
```

Whenever I disable them, thunderbird can retrieve email fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: At which stage is Thunderbird failing when trying to retrieve email?

Comment: Have you tried using the `LOG` feature of iptables to log which packets are being dropped? (you might be able to filter specifically thunderbird's packet if you run it as a different user and filter on that)

Comment: I repeatedly get this message: `Apr 25 10:53:30 user kernel: message_out_ipv6:IN= OUT=enp0s31f6 SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:5fe0:8278:e978:29a1 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0002 LEN=48 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=255 FLOWLBL=587658 PROTO=ICMPv6 TYPE=133 CODE=0` I can't figure out what it means..

Comment: May be this one? `Apr 25 10:56:33 user kernel: message_in_ipv6:IN=enp0s31f6 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:c4:71:fe:8c:67:7f:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:c671:feff:fe8c:677f DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=72 TC=224 HOPLIMIT=2>`

Comment: Please show the complete firewall, with `ip6tables -nvL`.

Answer (score 1):

What you see on logs or tcpdump? 
From other side some of Thunderbird and gmail tutorials (like https://oit.colorado.edu/tutorial/gmail-configure-thunderbird) suggest that it communicate with vendor site also on:
    Server hostname: smtp.gmail.com
    Port: 587
    SSL: STARTTLS
    Authentication: Normal Password

Comment: `sudo ip6tables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -p tcp --dport 587` did not solve it..

Comment: Still - please check what you see in logs or TCPdump as first method.

Comment: I'm getting this message `Apr 25 10:53:30 user kernel: message_out_ipv6:IN= OUT=enp0s31f6 SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:5fe0:8278:e978:29a1 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0002 LEN=48 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=255 FLOWLBL=587658 PROTO=ICMPv6 TYPE=133 CODE=0`